# .Net Core web application returns 500 - Internal server error

Tags: iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My new .Net Core web application (deployed on IIS) returns 500 - Internal server error.

I enabled stdoutLog, but the log file is not created. How can I debug it further?

ADDED:

Here is code from Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });       

services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

...        
      }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=MarketingTools}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does it run through your IDE?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, it does.

Comment: The log is pretty useless. That's just showing that a request was made for `favicon.ico` by a particular user agent at a particular IP, and the response code was 500, which you already know. Open a command prompt to the site's directory and then run `dotnet MyApp.dll`. You'll be able to monitor the startup and will see any exceptions that are thrown logged in the console window. If you get something, post it here along with the stack trace. If it starts up fine, then there's something wrong with the hosting bundle or IIS setup.

Comment: I found one issue. Removed authentication part from web.config. Now I get 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. The settings allow anonymous access...

Comment: 500.19 means invalid configuration. You need to use tools like Fiddler to see the actual error page generated by IIS, so as to know which line of your configuration file is wrong. For 403 errors, please also read IIS log files to learn its substatus code before doing anything else, https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0

Comment: 403.14 - Directory listing denied

Comment: If this is what 403 14 0 15 means...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you install this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle

Then run a basic .NET Core template app to test. Also like Chris mentioned run it from the command line to see potential error messages.

I was getting 500 without this installed.

Comment: Thank you Brian! But as I mentioned earlier in the comments to my question, "I found one issue. Removed authentication part from web.config. Now I get 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. The settings allow anonymous access." So I wonder how I can debug this. The logs folder is still empty. And IIS log has 2019-07-01 18:51:49 10.0.2.7 GET / - 443 - 216.41.121.33 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/75.0.3770.100+Safari/537.36 - 403 14 0 351

Comment: What does your Startup.cs look like? The web config gets generated. Do you have [Authorize] attribute on your controller/action? Try hitting a static html file and make sure you have app.UseStaticFiles(); in your Configure method. Usually for an authentication error you can set an access denied path in your cookie options. options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"); In IIS What does it say when you click .NET Authorization rules?

Comment: I added my startup.cs code to my original question. I don't use [Authorize] attribute so far. I did add a simple html page, and it showed up. IIS Authorization rules has "Allow all users". Is ".NET Authorization rules" something different? I don't see there such a thing. Thanks.